# "Luego luego" en México

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos, méxico

Escuchando los testimonios de la triste noticia de la explosión del mercado de fuegos artificiales en Tultepec México noté que muchas personas al contar su experiencia usan la expresión **"...luego luego..."**

Me parece que lo que quiere expresar es "... y después..." pero me gustaría que alguien dé una explicación más completa de los usos que los mexicanos le dan a "luego luego"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Su significado es más parecido a **inmediatamente** o **de inmediato**, se podría entender que es algo inmediatamente continuo a otro objeto, ya sea que se hable  de tiempo o de distancia.

Por ejemplo:

> La tienda esta **luego luego** del deportivo
>
> La tienda está **inmediatamente después** del deportivo
>
> Hoy me desperté **luego luego** que sonó la alarma
>
> Hoy me desperté **justo en el momento** que sonó la alarma

En el caso del tiempo la acción se puede asociar con algo en el mismo instante

Comment: Excelente. Aunque la idea que tenía era aproximada, esta explicación me ayuda a entender mejor a los hermanos Mexicanos.

Answer (score 0):

> luego luego: 1. loc. adv. enseguida.

Escuché a alguien diciendo que en Latinoamérica se usaba para decir "inmediatamente", en mi país no lo he escuchado, ni bromeando, porque de hecho suena gracioso, no tengo idea si se dirá así en Paraguay, pero de ser así, el significado parace ser distinto, tal vez quiso decir que él consideraba a México como un país perteneciente a Latinoamérica, lo que no es raro porque he leído que algunos mexicanos se identifican más con el término Latinoamérica que con América y por otro lado hay gente que sitúa mentalmente a todos los países de habla hispana en una misma región.

Sí lo he escuchado mucho en videos de mexicanos expertos en tecnología p.ej: No actualices **luego luego** que te llegue al móvil, espera a que la actualización tenga tiempo en el mercado para ver si otros usuarios tienen problemas.

> Por ejemplo, para El Salvador, 'luego luego' se refiere a las primeras horas del día, rápidamente o una acción que ocurre temprano. Mientras que en Paraguay significa 'de antemano' y en Honduras, 'ahora mismo'.